# Accessing local network site giving 401

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create a plugin to check some values hosted on a local site. the auth on the page is done via Windows Authentication.

so I was trying to create an xhr request, but that still gave me 401

```
// method 1
function get_information(link, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", link, true, "User","Password");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
}
```

same for an ajax request (with the webtoolkit.base64.js)

```
// method 2
function make_basic_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}

function get_info2(url){
  var auth = make_basic_auth('User','Password');
  $.ajax({
      url : url,
      method : 'GET',
      beforeSend : function(req) {
          req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
      }
  });
}
```

So is it just impossible to fetch that data in via an extention, or am I doing something wrong?